# How to take updates in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I go to visual studio tools > Extension and updates > updates .
I am seeing 4 updates but when I click on update button nothing is happening and one hyperlink is enable is as below.

"disable automatic detection of available updates"

Comment: Is your firewall disabled?  Sometimes the firewall prevents downloading.

Comment: No, Firewall is enable.