# Visual Studio 2013 Extensions and Updates - Update Button not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3 - Version 12.0.30723.00) I have 2 Extensions and Updates that appear but I cannot install them.  When I click on Update nothing happens.  I've tried to find separate downloads for these but I have had no luck.

Here is the only StackOverflow post that I've found that is similar: [How to take updates in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800824/how-to-take-updates-in-visual-studio-2013)

All other Extensions and Updates are able to be installed successfully.

The updates are:
Microsoft SQL Server Update for database tooling - I have v.12.0.40403.0 and it's trying to install 12.0.40706.0
Microsoft Azure SDK 2.4 - I have v 2.3 installed currently.

Comment: I found the Azure SDK 2.4 download link, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=323510&clcid=0x409 and that fixed 1/2 of the problem.

Comment: I did also try installing the [SSDT data tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) to try to fix the remaining issue, that didn't help either.

Comment: So now with VS 2013 Update 4 - I can't update that either, not clickable. Anyone else out there having this frustration?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found some guidance.

This [blog](http://blog.zerosharp.com/fix-visual-studio-update-links-when-running-as-administrator/) describes it well.

This was my exact scenario and uninstalling and re-installing chrome fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier this way:

Just set IE as your machine's default browser, and once you are done with installing updates, set you default browser back to whatever it was.