# How do I tell which version/update of Visual Studio 2013 I have currently installed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I click HELP in Visual Studio 2013 and About Microsoft Visual Studio, I see no details or information about which update my VS2013 is running. I know update release 5 just came out a few days ago, and my notifications only show me being able to upgrade to that.

But does that actually mean I'm on update 4 currently, or could I be on 3, and now that 5 is out, Microsoft wants me to skip to its most recent release?

How do I determine which release/update my VS 2013 is currently at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see no update information in the About dialog (e.g. Version 12.0.21005.1 REL) it means you are using the RTM version of VS 2013 without any updates. You can update directly to release 5 nevertheless.

Comment: In case someone wants to know other version numbers:  Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3 has the Version-Number 12.0.30723.00 [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815288/)
RTM: 12.0.21005.1, Update 1 -> 12.0.30110.0, Update 2 -> 12.0.30324.0,
Update 3 ->12.0.30723.0, Update 4 -> 12.0.31101.0, Update 5 -> 12.0.40629.0 [source](https://onemanwenttomow.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/visual-studio-2013-version-numbers-and-updates/)